# What is best practice for game screen mirroring for google-cast enabled devices?

Tags: android, google-cast

I would like to make android screen mirroring enabled game. If I understand correctly, in an official tictactoe sample all rendering is implemented twice (mobile device and on chromecast via html), I don't like to code same view rendering twice in two different languages.

What is simplest and what is best solution to achieve game screen mirroring?
Is it possible to use MediaRouter-s secondary display to achieve rendering on client side?
Is there any working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no support for mirroring your screen using the Cast SDK.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think out of the box screen mirroring. I was referring to add/write support code. Do you have any experience with http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarouter.html#secondary-output is this right way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Ops. In documentation, I see that only Remote Playback is supported in google cast. So only alternative is to write render code twice. What, if I try to generate some movie on the fly and start streaming it. I only need few frames per second. Is this a way to go? Is any chance that mirroring will be supported in near feature.

Comment: Presentation is not going to be helpful at this point since Cast device is not considered a secondary display. As for creating a movie and sending it over, it is doable but you had mentioned earlier that you are interested in mirroring games and most active games need at least 25+ frames per second.

Comment: I have very static game and idea is to cast game for observers (not players). What about if I use game engine like libgdx (http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) that supports Android/HTML5 backend and casting only game state and using only HTML backend rendering on chrome-cast device. HTML5 is generated with help of gwt project, will it work? Can you suggest starting steps ;)

Comment: You can register a custom receiver, served from a web server of your choice. In that receiver, you can have, say, an iframe, with Cast logic to expect to receive a message with a URL and when it does, it has to load that url inside that iframe. Now your mobile app should include a small web server and the page that you want to show on TV should be served up by that small web server inside your mobile app and its url should be sent to the chromecast device via your mobil app and its cast integration. (continued in the next comment due to space limit)

Comment: So you start your game and web server on mobile, you figure out the URL for the html page that you want to send to TV, you send a cast message to your TV (using a custom namespace) and your receiver on Chromecast knows what to do with that URL: it opens that url inside the iframe that is there. You can send reload commands to your receiver so your receiver reloads the content of iframe if there are changes that you want to refresh.

Comment: Thx. What if: I  have native sender app (game) that generates unique key, than I send that key to the custom receiver and server (GAE) that hosts GAE game "room" (instead of suggested mobile Web server). Than Chromecast opens/renders that room. This way almost all communication goes SenderMobileApp1 <--> GAE <--> ChromeCast (Ajax html). With this architecture I can broadcast game to the web and to many Chromecast devices simultaneously.

Comment: I am not familiar with GAE, but if your html page is available from another server in the cloud and the token you referred to is adequate for the receiver to access that content, then sure, do that; that sounds better (the less you depend on your phone, in general, the better).

Answer (score 1):

I have written a few replies about this: if you use the ChromeCast app and apply screen mirroring, you CAN show JUST your Presentation class on the chromecast.

The only problem is that you cannot use the mediaroute Button to start this: you have to start the chromecast app and apply screen mirroring from that. I have yet to find a way to use the mediaroute button to start screencasting only my Presentation.

Comment: so can I uses a view from my code to be mirrored using Presentation API ? is their a code example for same ?

Comment: Yes. Check out the ChromeCast SDK developer pages for a sample howto.